# How to create tabs in JFace Custom Dialog?

Tags: swt, jface

Hi I want to replicate the appearance of tabbed properties view in a custom dialog.
But I dont know how to create tabs in it.
Can anyone suggest how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with dialogs.

You simply create your `TabFolder` control on top of the dialog's `dialogArea`, and that's pretty much everything to it.

[See this example on how to create a SWT Tab Control](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTTabControl.htm)